# Best Practice for Filterable Dropdown with Nested Lists using Elementor and Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, elementor

StackOverflow community!

I've been working on a project where I'm using Elementor for WordPress. While Elementor provides a fantastic way to design and layout content, I've had to hardcode a specific feature: a filterable dropdown with nested lists.

Objective:
When a user types in the search box (inside the dropdown), I want the dropdown to filter and display only the relevant links. This means showing or hiding both the "region" and its associated links based on the user's input.

For instance, if a user types "San Miguel Ranch", only "Southern California" (its parent "region") and the "San Miguel Ranch" link should be visible. If none of the associated links under a "region" match the search criteria, the "region" itself should also be hidden.

We are trying to imitate this website search feature, https://www.watermarkcommunities.com/our-communities/

Here's a screenshot,  https://prnt.sc/tNEilEwIrtPi

Here's the code I've come up with:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Explore Our Communities" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
        <div id="down" class="down">
            <ul>
                <li class="region"> <a href="#">Southern California</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/san-miguel-ranch">San Miguel Ranch</a></li>
                    <!-- ... other links ... -->
                </ul>
                <!-- ... other regions and their links ... -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

   <script>
    /* Script Functions */
    function filterFunction() {
        let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        let div = document.getElementById("down");
        let regions = div.getElementsByClassName("region");

        for (let i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
            let a = regions[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            let ul = regions[i].nextElementSibling;
            let li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            let matchFound = false;
            for (let j = 0; j < li.length; j++) {
                if (li[j].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[j].style.display = "";
                    matchFound = true;
                } else {
                    li[j].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            // If match is found in one of the communities, show the parent city
            if (matchFound) {
                regions[i].style.display = "";
                ul.style.display = "";
            } else {
                regions[i].style.display = "none";
                ul.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can you review the code and suggest best practices or improvements? I'm especially interested in the JavaScript filtering function and any potential optimizations or pitfalls I might've missed.

Thank you for your time and expertise!

P.S. Should I hardcode this or use custom fields or custom post type? Please advise.

I tried hardcoding it. I am not sure if it's the best practice.